# Method for caramelizing Goat Cheese Balls without Breading?

Tags: cheese, frying, deep-frying, restaurant-mimicry, caramelization

I was recently at a restaurant where I was served fried balls of goat cheese. They were white, oily, very slightly browned, and appeared to be without any breading. The outside of the balls were sweet. The texture was very soft and fairly consistent; it reminded me of fresh goat cheese, only slightly denser.

They were served slightly warmer than lukewarm in an otherwise cold salad.

The menu described them as "Caramelized Goat Cheese". I am completely out of my wits how they were made.

My best guess is that the cheese balls were formed in molds were glazed honey and then frozen. The frozen cheese balls were either deep fried or torched. I wonder if a specific type of cheese or a mixture containing non-cheese ingredients is needed to make this.

I am hoping to replicate these and I am looking for a recipe. How were they made?

Comment: Do [these](https://thethingswellmake.com/easy-festive-caramelized-goat-cheese-salad-walnuts/) look like what you were served?

Comment: @Halhex No, they were spherical and not cylindrical. I didn't have the impression that it was a matured tomme du chèvre, but something fresher. Very smooth texture.

Comment: I did not make balls but you can caramelize slices and pieces of Feta in butter or olive oil , I add a sprinkle of lemon juice.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a mini [scooper](https://www.google.com/search?q=mini%20scooper&newwindow=1&client=firefox-b-d&channel=crow&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=wZRs8rZXk9mJ6M%253A%252C7nxJH6m1Gs4VGM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kTUYFhSVVcQCrwMQ8iVk6ST1JuVxg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjipKf38ojjAhXYTX0KHeU1Bz8Q9QEwBHoECAkQDA#imgrc=wZRs8rZXk9mJ6M:) to cut the goat cheese in spherical shape. After cutting the spheres, put a toothpick to it, coat it with castor sugar or dermerra sugar. Blow torch it evenly on all sides. Enjoy!!

Comment: What kind of goat cheese should I use?